# What changes we need to do in the android application to make it multiwindow application?

Tags: android

Is it sufficient to add `<category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER"/>` line in the     androidManifest.xml file to make it compatible for multiWindow?

Or do we have to make some more changes in the androidManifest.xml file?

Along with this androidManifest.xml file. Do we need to call some API method in the activity class to make it compatible with MultiWindow?

Answer (score 0):

> is it sufficient to add  line in the androidManifest.xml file to make it compatible for multiWindow.

That category is not part of the N Developer Preview 2, based on the documentation. You do not need it to have a multi-window app. I would expect this to be documented and explained in a future preview.

> or we have to so some more changes in the androidManifest.xml file.

Activities are automatically multi-window capable, except for those with a `targetSdkVersion` of 23 or below and a fixed orientation via `android:screenOrientation`.

> we need to call some API method in the activity class to make it compatible with MultiWindow.

No.

You are welcome to read [the documentation on making your app multi-window friendly](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/multi-window.html#configuring), though.