# is it necessary to add the MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER intent category into the launcher activity?

Tags: android

is it necessary to add the MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER intent category into 
`<category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />`
 into the launcher activity.

if i add this in any non launcher activity , then what will happen ?

Comment: [As I told you previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36824212/115145): "That category is not part of the N Developer Preview 2, based on the documentation. You do not need it to have a multi-window app. I would expect this to be documented and explained in a future preview."

Comment: hey i was asking this question by considering the samsung and LG devices MULTIWINDOW support feature.

Comment: They did something else, apparently independently of what Google is adding in Android N. When referring to "multi-window" now, it will be important for you to indicate whether you are referring to the official Android multi-window support or some manufacturer-specific implementation.

Comment: yes i am asking this by considering manufacturer-specific implementation .  so tell me something from manufacturer-specific implementation point of view.

Comment: i am developing an android application  , in that i have added the multi-window feature that can run on  samsung or LG devices  so i want to ask that is it necessary to add (MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER category intent) in launcher activity or we can add this in any other activity.